# ACI - VNET - IP Address

Tags: azure-container-instances

I have created Virtual Network and connected API Management to Virtual Network.

I am thinking to host my REST API in Azure Container Instances in my VNET and then expose those API in Azure API Management by configuring IP Address of Azure Container Instance REST API into Azure API Management web service url.

I have one doubt, if this is right way of doing it.

I am wondering if Azure Container Instance gets restarted and if IP Address will change, then my API exposed in API Mangament will be broken. Does IP Address gets changed if Azure Container Instances gets restarted for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update#limitations) for Azure container instances.

> **The IP address of a container won't typically change between updates**,
>   but it's not guaranteed to remain the same. **As long as the container
>   group is deployed to the same underlying host, the container group
>   retains its IP address**. Although rare, and while Azure Container
>   Instances makes every effort to redeploy to the same host, there are
>   some Azure-internal events that can cause redeployment to a different
>   host. To mitigate this issue, always use a DNS name label for your
>   container instances.
>
> Terminated or deleted container groups can't be updated. Once a
>   container group has stopped (is in the Terminated state) or has been
>   deleted, the group is deployed as new.

However, It's a **rare case** that Azure container instances will be redeployed to a different host. Also, if you have a container instance in a VNet, you're unable to directly set a `--dns-name-label` value and you only could access the instance via its private IP address from the outside world and other container groups. *Note: Containers in a group are not discoverable through DNS. They can only be accessed through ‘localhost’, in combination with their exposed ports.* You could get more references from *More about networking* in this [blog](https://xpirit.com/containers-as-a-service-in-azure/).